# Unable to Locate a Specific Word inside a List of Items

Tags: python, list

> This is my list :

```
print(checklist)

"A year on, AASU observes 'Black Day' to protest against CAA", u'Assam: Cargo reaches Lower Subansiri HE Project site despite protests', u'CAA will grant citizenship to 1.9 cr Hindu Bangladeshis in Assam: Akhil Gogoi', u'7 foods to increase estrogen levels in women', u'Meghalaya CM Conrad Sangma tests COVID-19 positive, has mild symptoms', u'AJYCP holds protest rally against CAA in Naharkatia', u"'Cash for job' scam: AMCH doctor's husband detained for interrogation", u"Meet 23-year-old Jojo Rajkumari, Manipur's first woman MMA fighter", u'Here are some food items to reduce heartburn and acid reflux']
```

> This is how I am checking for a String inside this list :

```
matches = ["AASU", "Black Day"]
if  matches in checklist:
    print('found')
else:
    print('not found')
         
print(checklist)
```

> It is always returning Not Found. but as you can see its present there. How to solve it ? please Guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you are doing when you call `if  matches in checklist:` is you are checking if the variable "matches" exists in "checklist".

This means you are looking if the **list** `matches` exists exactly like that in the `list` checklist.

But that's not what you actually want. You want to see if **any of the entries in matches** exists **in any of the entries in checklist**.

To check this you need to loop over these values. A loop means you basically do a lot of checks after another.

If you use a loop like:

```
for item in checklist:
```

You now have an loop that for every entry in checklist assumes the value of that item in a variable named "item".

Next you need to realize that your "matches" list also has multiple entries, so you need to loop over it as well:

```
for match in matches:
```

Will loop over every entry in matches and write the value in the variable "match".

Now you can compare the two and do a check:

```
if match in item:
```

This will trigger if the string in "match" exists in the string in "item".

So some code like

```
checklist=["A year on, AASU observes 'Black Day' to protest against CAA", u'Assam: Cargo reaches Lower Subansiri HE Project site despite protests', u'CAA will grant citizenship to 1.9 cr Hindu Bangladeshis in Assam: Akhil Gogoi', u'7 foods to increase estrogen levels in women', u'Meghalaya CM Conrad Sangma tests COVID-19 positive, has mild symptoms', u'AJYCP holds protest rally against CAA in Naharkatia', u"'Cash for job' scam: AMCH doctor's husband detained for interrogation", u"Meet 23-year-old Jojo Rajkumari, Manipur's first woman MMA fighter", u'Here are some food items to reduce heartburn and acid reflux']
matches = ["AASU", "Black Day"]
for item in checklist:
    for match in matches:
        if match in item:
            print("found")
```

Will print "found" for every instance of a entry in "match" existing in your original list.

If you want to know the match simply modify it like this (I'll not rewrite the variable assignments from here on out)

```
for item in checklist:
    for match in matches:
        if match in item:
            print("Found! \""+match+"\" was found in \""+item+"\"!")
```

If you want to know "where" in the list your entry was found you either need to use counting variables or work with indexes.

```
for i in range(len(checklist)):
    for j in range(len(matches)):
        if matches[j] in checklist[i]:
            print("Found! \""+matches[j]+"\" was found in \""+checklist[i]+"\", at position: "+str(i))
```

As Mark Meyer noted this checks if the string in "matches" exists in the string in "checklist", so if you have a word that is part of a compound word it will return true.

For example if you have "sour" in the checklist it will consider "sourdough" a valid example. If you want to ONLY check for the word alone the way I'd do so is with some additional checks. This makes the program a lot more complicated and is not perfect, but you'll get the idea:

```
checklist=["A year on, AASU observes 'Black Day' to protest against CAA", u'Assam: Cargo reaches Lower Subansiri HE Project site despite protests', u'CAA will grant citizenship to 1.9 cr Hindu Bangladeshis in Assam: Akhil Gogoi', u'7 foods to increase estrogen levels in women', u'Meghalaya CM Conrad Sangma tests COVID-19 positive, has mild symptoms', u'AJYCP holds protest rally against CAA in Naharkatia', u"'Cash for job' scam: AMCH doctor's husband detained for interrogation", u"Meet 23-year-old Jojo Rajkumari, Manipur's first woman MMA fighter", u'Here are some food items to reduce heartburn and acid reflux']
matches = ["AASU", "Black Day"]
for i in range(len(checklist)):
    for j in range(len(matches)):
        if matches[j] in checklist[i]:
            pos=checklist[i].find(matches[j])
            if pos!=0:
                if not checklist[i][pos-1].isalpha() and not checklist[i][pos+len(matches[j])].isalpha():
                    print("Found! \""+matches[j]+"\" was found in \""+checklist[i]+"\", at position: "+str(i))
            elif pos==0:
                if not checklist[i][pos+len(matches[j])].isalpha():
                    print("Found! \""+matches[j]+"\" was found in \""+checklist[i]+"\", at position: "+str(i))
```

The idea is to make sure it's not part of another word by checking the letter one before your match and one after and looking if it's a letter or something else. If it's a letter it's part of another word.

The check if "pos"==0 is done to make sure it's not at the beginning of the string, because then looking up the letter one before that would result in a out of range error.

Comment: Might be worth clarifying whether the OP intends to match only whole words. For example, if `matches = ['serves']` should this print "found" because `observes` is in the sentence?

Comment: That's a good observation, I didn't consider that. I can modify the code to do so, but it would make it a lot more complicated. I will add it to illustrate though.

Comment: Thank You for the Help. Answer Accepted !  @MarkMeyer has a good Point. I only wanted to match the Exact whole word from the matches list

Comment: Sorry that it took me a bit, but I added a version that only matches whole words. Might have bugs, but seemed to work for me in my limited testing.